# How to send emails with subscription box inside?

Tags: php, email, web

I want to send emails to users which have subscription box inside ,so that these users who have subscribed to my website newsletters.

Is it possible? And if yes then how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As one of solutions, you could use php function [mail](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to send your users email which contains unique (for each user) link. If the user follows that link (say he opens it and is asked to log in, to confirm that that's your user), then he is subscribed to your newsletter.

P.S. As already asked in comments, you should post something you've already tried to get detailed answers.